# Show Excerpts on Video Category Page Only?

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now, I made my whole wordpress blog display the_excerpt instead of the_content. But, I would like it to show the_content only on the video category page. Right now in the content.php files it grabs the extension "muimedia_post_entry_summary" from my content extensions php file. In my content extensions php file here is the code that gets the excerpt (post_entry_summary)...

```
/* muimedia_post_entry_summary */
if ( !function_exists( 'muimedia_post_entry_summary' ) ) {
function muimedia_post_entry_summary() {
?>
<div class="entry-summary">
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail()){ ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute
( array('before' =>          esc_attr__( 'Permalink: ', 'muimedia' ), 
'after' => ''));  ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
<div id="categorysummary">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
}
```

This code gets each post's thumbnail and excerpt.. and I'm trying to get it to show the content ONLY on the videos category page. I tried keeping the first code above, duplicating it then changing it to the following:

```
/* muimedia_post_entry_summary video page */
if ( !function_exists( 'muimedia_post_entry_summary' ) && is_category( 'videos' )  ) {
function muimedia_post_video_entry_summary() {
?>
<div class="entry-content">
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

}

As you can see I tried the "&& is_category", I also tired "|| is_category" and also replacing the category name with it's ID. I even tried changing the function name so it's "post_video_entry_summary" (I don't think this name matters to be honest). I don't really know what else to do :( If anyone could help me on this small issue it would meann soooo sooo much to me! It really would. I'm going to go eat some lunch. But, I will make my return to my computer within the next 20 mins.. Hopefully someone will have the right solution to this some what minimal problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

use 'in_category("video")' as your if statement.

```
<?php 
    if (in_category('videos')) : 
?>

    // your video code here

<?php 
    else : 
?>

    // else show the current stuff

<?php 
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hi, not to be rude but I think the problem is much bigger than that. It has to do with my specific second code that I listed to show the excerpt only on the video.. I tried what you sugested:

/* muimedia_post_entry_summary video page */
if ( in_category('videos')  ) {
  function muimedia_post_video_entry_summary() {
  ?>
  <div class="entry-content">
   
   
   <?php the_content(); ?>
   
  </div>
  <?php
 }
}
I also tried is_category and still nothing.. I appreciate the help though! :)

Comment: If anyone else has an answer it would mean a lot to me! :)

Comment: Hi the category is titled "videos". My blog is ran through a php file called content extensions. So in my content php it has a code like <? php do_action('muimedia_post_entry_summary'); ?>. Then in the content extensions I have to write code for the post_entry_summary. I already have a code that displays the excerpt for the post entry summary, now I'm trying to get it to show the excerpt just in the videos category page (code listed in OP). And the traditional "is_category" or "in_category" isn't working. :(  Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: i'm not sure why in_category is not resolving for you. i use the above example in my loop to display video, gallery, featured image and standard posts differently. you can also use the same conditioning on a page.php or single.php.